# Tag Descriptions in Evernote?

Tags: evernote, tags

In Evernote, is it possible to add descriptions to the tags that we use? Something similar to the tag descriptions and tag wiki that we have in SE sites?

If yes, where can I find them and how can I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Evernote has no tag descriptions *per se*, but you may use a separate tag to define the tag desciptions and use it in following way:

- Create a note with a tag description and tag it with **description** and the described tag (for example **description** and **recipes**). Give the note a title **"Tag description: recipes"**
- When you need to look for the list of tag descriptions, look for all notes tagged **description** and you will get the list of all tag descriptions.
- When you need to look for the description of a tag, type in search box **tag:description** and the tag name (for example **"tag:description tag:recipes**) and you'll get the description of this tag.
- You may change the description note's creation time to some date in the past, so that it will appear in the end of the list of all notes tagged with the tag.